# Sending commands to an STM32 chip via UART with Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: serial

I am having trouble making an Arduino Pro Mini send commands via USART to an STM32 chip. The serial communication protocol is currently set to 9600 baud rate with no flow control or stop bits. Is there anything special that has to be done to make these two devices communicate with each other? I'm using the standard RX/TX pins for this. The Arduino logic level is 3.3V. The STM32 logic level is 2.5V. They share a common ground. I should also note that there is a 1K ohm resistor in series with each data line. Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h> 

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  delay(4000);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                      
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
  delay(1000);                       
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
  delay(1000);                       
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
  delay(1000);
  String voltage = String("85 2 0 0 10 174 96"); //Command to set voltage output on STM32
  Serial.println(voltage);

  while (1) {  
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   
    delay(200);                       
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    
    delay(200);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Nothing special needs to be done. Beyond that, we can't really help you without seeing some code.

Comment: Do the chips share a common ground? Do they use the same logic voltage levels? Are they both powered? Did you connect the Arduino's TX to the STM32's RX? Do you have a scope?

Comment: Please see the edited post. They are both definitely powered and the RX/TX lines are wired correctly.

Comment: I see nothing wrong _on the Arduino side_. Are you sure the STM32 expects text rather than binary? Does it like the CRLF line termination? Is its RX 3.3V-tolerant?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the STM32 is 3.3V tolerant. I haven't tried binary. I will give that a go. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: What is your stm code and why is it powered at 2.5V?

Comment: Just a quick note: confirm that the STM is 3.3V tolerant even when Vcc is 2.5V; this is because most of the times the upper value is Vcc+0.3V. Even though, I'm confident it is compatible with the voltage range.

Comment: Moreover, check with an oscilloscope on the serial line, so that you can detect whether the issue is with the arduino or the STM

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the STM code. I added a voltage divider to the Arduino TX to bring it down to 2.5V. I tried transmitting binary code with no luck. Is it possible that I need to convert the values in the string to ASCII characters since it's USART? I will take a look with an oscilloscope when I try again.

Comment: I finally figured it out! I ended up having to declare the values in the string as integers, and then I used serial.write() instead of serial.print(). Thank you everyone for your help!